# Roles.GetRolesForUser() in Layout view not returning roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

`@Roles.GetRolesForUser()` in razor layout view is not returning roles. `@Roles.GetRolesForUser().Count()` is 0.

While `@Roles.IsUserInRole('name_of_logged_in_role')` returns `true` in the same view at the same place.

Razor View:

```
<p>
    @User.Identity.Name //Output: MyName
    @Roles.GetRolesForUser().Count()  //Output: 0
    @Roles.IsUserInRole("Radiologist")  //Output: True
</p>
```

**Update**

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name).Length //Output: 0
@Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.GetUserName()).Length //Output: 0
```

Comment: Are you changing the roles prior to this layout being executed?  If so, you may be experiencing an issue with the cookie role cache being used for GetRolesForUser.  See the section on CacheRolesInCookie here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does it give you the same result if you did this `GetRolesForUser(username here)`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil No I am not changing roles. Stays same even if I do it a private window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive research, I finally found the problem.  I was able to reproduce the issue in a web application.  Apparently, you cannot combine **ASP.NET Identity** with **Simple Membership**, simply like you did so with the `GetRolesForUser` method.  The `Roles` object is by default setup for **Simple Membership** using a default provider, but it seems like your using **ASP.NET Identity** not **Simple Membership**.  I didn't even notice the difference until I was wondering myself why it wasnt working.

The reason why you got `string[0]` is because `GetRolesForUser` executed an sql query to a table that doesnt exist in your database.
The reason why `IsUserInRole` worked was more or less it did not even use the default provider to check it used the `CacheRolesInCookie`

```
If CacheRolesInCookie is true, then roleName may be checked against the roles cache rather than the specified role provider.
```

So, technically it went to a connectionString that was listed by the default provider and return `string[0]` because you have no data in the database with that connectionString.  Adding your current database to the providers would not help either because **Simple Membership** database schema is different from **ASP.NET Identity**

That being said, you should get the roles by UserName like this:

Simple Solution:

```
public List<string> GetRoles(string UserName)
{    List<string> roles = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
    {
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var account = new AccountController();

        roles = account.UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);         
    }            
    return roles;
}
```

**Updated**

Extended Solution:

You could extend the **ASP.NET Identity** Roles in your context

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799571/ASP-NET-MVC-Extending-ASP-NET-Identity-Roles

Comment: I am already using Identity Roles in my Application. I had no idea that GetRolesForUser belongs to simple membership. I am still unable to get role in layout view

Comment: @LifeH2O, what is happening when you use that code from the other post or have you solved your problem already?

Comment: `GetRolesForUser` was returning `0` no matter what. As you explained, it was doing so because this method belongs to `SimpleMembership` while I was using `Identity` to manage roles. So I used the code from that post to show role in my view which uses `UserManager` to get roles.